# Is it correct to say "demand somebody that something be done"?

Tags: word-usage, subjunctives

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? Is it correct to say "demand somebody that something be done"?

> He demanded her that the books she borrowed from him be returned.

Comment: No, it's not correct. In the transitive verb ***to demand X***, that ***X*** has to be ***something** you're asking **for*** (the thing wanted), not ***someone** you want something **from*** (the person being asked). You need to include a preposition in your example: *He demanded **of her** that the books she borrowed from him [should] be returned* (but the highlighted words don't have to be included at all; it's perfectly grammatical to demand things without specifying ***from whom***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, but no.

The only object of “to demand” is what you are demanding; it doesn’t take an indirect object. So, we usually structure the demand as an active phrase:

> He demanded (that) she return the books (that) she had borrowed from him.

If it is not clear from the demand or other context who the demand is being made of, as in your example with a passive phrase, you could insert a prepositional phrase before it:

> He demanded **of her** that the books she borrowed from him be returned.

This feels a bit awkward. Sometimes it is unavoidable, but if you can rephrase the demand from passive to active, that is much preferred.